# How to deal with bad data in Google Calendar .ics file

Tags: google-calendar-api, icalendar

Our website uses php to read a google calendar in .ics file format which is maintained by an end user.  It fetches this URL:

https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/dogsport.org%40hotmail.com/public/basic.ics

The problem is that somehow bad data gets in there... i.e. data that is for a calendar event which does not appear when you view the calendar in google.  But nonetheless it is an event in the .ics file.    Two examples are below...

So the question is, is there a way to recognize that the data is bad and ignore it in my php script too?

Two examples of what I mean...  these appear in ics file but do not appear in the google calendar display of the calendar.

```
SUMMARY: Reg/Nat Prep - SHORT Wk 1
DTSTART: 20150730T183000
DTEND: 20150730T200000
RRULE: FREQ=WEEKLY;COUNT=2;BYDAY=TH
DTSTAMP: 20150801T221348Z
UID: osk40g350ccpukjah3q6aj6110_R20150731T003000@google.com
CREATED: 20150731T001352Z
DESCRIPTION: 
LAST-MODIFIED: 20150731T001504Z
LOCATION: 
SEQUENCE: 1
STATUS: CONFIRMED
TRANSP: TRANSPARENT



SUMMARY: Reg/Nat Prep Class - SHORT Wk 1
DTSTART: 20150730T183000
DTEND: 20150730T200000
RRULE: FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20150731T002959Z;BYDAY=TH
DTSTAMP: 20150801T221348Z
UID: osk40g350ccpukjah3q6aj6110@google.com
CREATED: 20150731T001352Z
DESCRIPTION: 
LAST-MODIFIED: 20150731T001504Z
LOCATION: 
SEQUENCE: 1
STATUS: CONFIRMED
TRANSP: TRANSPARENT
```

Comment: What's 'bad' about this data? I doubt your examples is exaclty how it appears... seems poorly copy pasted, but why should it not show up in the calendar?

Comment: Thanks for commenting that the data looks good... if so then really what it seems to boil down to is the google calendar is simply not displaying it properly.   PS.  To see the actual data visit the hotlink:   https://www.google.com/calendar/ical/dogsport.org%40hotmail.com/public/basic.ics   The two examples I mention do not show on the google-rendered calendar which you can see if you go to google calendar (https://www.google.com/calendar/render?tab=wc#main_7) and use the "add a friends calendar" to add dogsport.org@hotmail.com.

Comment: These events are missing timezone from the start and end. There should be a Z at the end or a TZID.